# Opening CMD From Same Place - Different UIs

Tags: windows-10, command-line, cmd.exe

I've been working on making my Windows partition as productive-focused as my Linux is, and I've run into something...odd. I tried searching for answers, but I had no idea how to express the issue. The title is as close as I could come, and searching with that got me nowhere.

**BACKGROUND:**

I have customized the CMD UI so that I can tolerate it. I normally start it via <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>, type `cmd`, and I get the customized version. The same happens if I navigate to `C:\Windows\System32` and double-click on `cmd.exe` (which I expected would be the case, as that would be where it would find CMD).

I decided to set up a keyboard shortcut, so I made the desktop shortcut for CMD, and when I double-clicked on it I got the ugly,default version of CMD. Looking at the properties for the shortcut, the target is `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe`, which is what has been opening up the customized UI.

Essentially, the shortcut and Run dialog-box open the same executable, in the same place, but the UIs are different. I couldn't find any option in the shortcut properties for opening with any presets, and I actually have no clue where the settings are for the prettier UI, as I set it up a long time ago.

**QUESTION:**

Why does opening CMD from the Run box and the desktop shortcut open different looking sessions, when using the same executable? How can I make them open with the same UI, namely the customized UI?

Comment: That's because [shortcuts store their own console settings](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130527-00/?p=4253) independently. If you open via the shortcut and set the defaults again, they should stick for that shortcut.

Comment: It's an interesting question. What you do to customize the UI might be a substantial hint to why this happen.

Comment: @Vylix I just changed font size, color, maybe font type. Just some superficial changes because default is beyond annoying.

Comment: @Bob Interesting. I assume that CMD opens and reads a config file to open with the right font size, etc. Is there a central config file that all instances would read that I could just edit?

Comment: @Ungeheuer Console settings (Win32 console subsystem; conhost.exe) are not controlled by nor read by cmd. cmd just just the most well-known user - but any other console program, e.g. powershell, will use the exact same Console subsystem. As for a central default; I don't know, sorry.

Comment: @Ungeheuer Use edit > defaults to change all cmd windows, edit > properties to change the current cmd window